# Intersecting Nodes

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a for loop that will generate a trail of SKSpriteNodes with NO physics body

```
   for _ in 1..<25 {
       drawBlocks()
}
```

I have a playerObject (a ball) that HAS a physics body.

I'm trying to run a method that when the playerObject intersects one of the SKSPriteNodes generated from my for loop, the SKSpriteNode will disappear.

In my update method I have this

```
if block.frame.intersects(playeObject.frame) == true {
blocks.removeFromParent()
}
```

I tried to add a print statement if the method is actually being called when the two intersect but they don't. Any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also make a physicsBody to your blocks without give to these block the dynamic property set to true (false = static object),so for each block:

```
block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFromRect: block.frame)
block.physicsBody?.mass = 1
block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
block.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
block.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
block.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.Block.rawValue
block.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes. PlayerObject.rawValue
```

About your CollisionTypes could be:

```
enum CollisionTypes: UInt32 {
    case Block = 1
    case PlayerObject = 2
}
```

Add to your `playerObject.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask` also the block , and check for the contacts between blocks and player directly to `didBeginContact`

Comment: I am actually using physics body on the blocks but I'm trying to avoid that. Is that my only option?

Comment: When you have to do with a physic ambient the best way is to follow physics rules, otherwise you could replicate all your phisic environments with SKActions, so the answer is : yes you should use physicsbody to blocks to detect collisions,

Comment: Okay, I'l accept your answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Physics would make this easier, though would require more processing. Using physics you would have the option to use didBeginContact() notify you of a contact. Note that your player object would need to be dynamic, while the other objects could be static (dynamic = false). Static objects do not generate collisions with other static objects.

Without using physics what you have should work You will need to check for a collision in update().

Comment: I am actually using physics body on the blocks but I'm trying to avoid that. Is that my only option?

Comment: You can use frame intersects, be sure both sprites share the same parent.